# iOS: Show Modal View Controller with full screen image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want to show a fullscreen image when a thumbnail is tapped. Right now I'm presenting a modal view controller, but the image is not centered in the screen:

[image]

Here's the code I'm using in the modal view controller to present the view controller:

```
UIViewController *modalCon = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

modalCon.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
modalCon.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:modalCon.view.frame];
imageView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.image=coverImage.image;

[modalCon.view addSubview:imageView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *modalTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissModalView)];
[modalCon.view addGestureRecognizer:modalTap];

[self presentViewController:modalCon animated:YES completion:nil];
```

How do I get this image centered in the view controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try  `[image view setCenter:self.view.center]`
that one centres according to screen but if you want to centre to modalCon then replace `self.view` to `modalCon.view`

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You're original suggestion does work. Thanks! Still don't understand why this question was downvoted.